# Write in Machine's Description Field of Windows Active Directory from a MacBook Machine

Tags: macos, unix, active-directory

I will need to write a script to modify the "description" attribute of the Macbook computer account in the Windows Active Directory with the values like username, serial number of the MacBooks, time of last login.

```
 I had managed to write same script like this requirement for Windows machines, and the script is working well (VBS Code). I have give permissions in the Active Directory so the "description" attributes of a account could be modified from external sources.

  Is this requirement is feasible to be done, if yes - could anybody guide me on how writing the required script. Thank you very much for your help.
```